# Python Version + Requirement

Tags: python, github, styles, coding-style, requirements.txt

I should upload a Python program to GitHub and I was wondering about two things:

- does it make sense to upload an empty requirement.txt (the file was requested)
- where should I mention the version of Python I used to code my program?

Comment: Do you mean your program doesn't require anything but the standard library? In that case, I wouldn't bother including an empty requirements file. If you need a specific version of Python (beyond just "3.x") you could put that in a README.

Comment: github mostly doesn't care about these. These only matter if you are going to upload this as a package to pypi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not using any external libraries, I dont think you need to add a requirements.txt file.
You should mention the version of python that you used in a README file.